# unequal interval level in pyplot.contourf

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

I use plt.contourf and draw the figure, and I would like to use levels with different spacing:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.random.rand(10,10)*70-32 # I want my data between +/-70
levels = [-32, -16,-8, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
im = plt.contourf(data, levels)
im.set_cmap('Set1')
plt.colorbar()
plt.contour(data, levels=[0], colors='black')
```

[image]

black contour is 0-value line for check
and we can find the zero value in contourf is missing.
does anyone know what happened in contourf?

or any suggestion for this issue with different spacing in level?

thank you very much

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine on my computer. What version of python/MPL are you using? Have you tried different colormaps and different data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `"Set1"` has only 9 colors. So if you have more levels, some levels have the same color. You can choose a colormap with more discrete colors and specify a `BoundaryNorm` with the levels you have.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors

data = np.random.rand(10,10)*70-32 
levels = [-32, -16,-8, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(levels,len(levels))
im = plt.contourf(data, levels, cmap="tab20c", norm=norm)

plt.colorbar(ticks=levels)
plt.contour(data, levels=[0], colors='black')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or you take a colormap with more continuous levels and leave the rest the same.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.rand(10,10)*70-32 
levels = [-32, -16,-8, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]

im = plt.contourf(data, levels, cmap="magma")

plt.colorbar(ticks=levels)
plt.contour(data, levels=[0], colors='black')
plt.show()
```

[image]